# How do I limit selecting loans that are beyond 12/31/2018?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get away from using PTP dates and just use ACH's. I am trying to return loans with billing dates under 12/31/18. How do I limit this?

I already tried some date formats.

```
SELECT        
    ach.acctrefno, 
    ach.billing_next_date, 
    DATEADD(mm, 1, billing_next_date) billing_next_period, 
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) today, 
    ach.status
FROM 
    loanacct_ach ach
WHERE        
    (ach.billing_next_date > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)) 
    AND (ach.billing_next_date < DATEADD(mm, 1, ach.billing_next_date))
ORDER BY 
    ach.billing_next_date
```

How do I limit it to return those loans that are less than 12/31/2018?

Comment: `... and ach.billing_next_date < '2018-12-31'...`  ?  Why won't that work?

Comment: End of 'GetDate()' year is like `DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, -1, GETDATE()), 0)-1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't the logic just be this?

```
SELECT ach.*
FROM loanacct_ach ach
WHERE ach.billing_next_date < '2019-01-01'
```